# Google Groups Settings API 500 Error

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to update group settings via web API request. All necessary authorization scopes are provided and groups settings are enabled. I send a put request:

```
body = {
    "whoCanPostMessage": "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST",
    "whoCanViewMembership": "ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW"
}
response = requests.put(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/%s" % group_id,
    data=json.dumps(body),
    headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }
)
```

but the server responds:

```
<Response [500]> Internal Server Error

headers:
Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  122
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Fri, 05 Feb 2016 18:36:53 GMT
Expires:  Fri, 05 Feb 2016 18:36:53 GMT
Server:  GSE
Vary:  Origin, X-Origin

content:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

The same error occurs when I use [Try It!](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/update#try-it) in the Groups Settings API Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `UniqueGroupID` field should be set to a group email address not a group id. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [Google Groups for business](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167096https://support.google.com/a/answer/167096?hl=en) enabled in your domain?